# Is it possible for a forest node to have more than one parent?

Tags: arrows, forest

I have this Forest :

```latex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        draw,
        align=center
    },
    forked edges,
    [A,name=CEO
        [B
            [C]
            [D,draw,red,name=ME]
        ]
    ]
    \draw[-] (CEO) to[out=east,in=east] (ME);
    \node [draw, fit=(current bounding box.south east) (current bounding box.north west)] {};
\end{forest}
```

Which gives me this :

[image]

Cursorily looking at the `forest` [documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/forest/0), I can't find how to make D be a child of both `B` and `A`.

The only thing I found is that `\draw[-] (CEO) to[out=east,in=east] (ME);` but I find it especially ugly, so I would want it to be like this Mermaid graph (with straight lines, of course) :

```
flowchart TD;
    A --- B;
    B --- C;
    B --- D;
    A --- D;
```

[image]

Comment: No, because `forest` is specifically designed for drawing trees and these are not trees. For drawing graphs like this you may want to use the  `graphdrawing` library of TikZ (requires LuaLaTeX for compilation). Or do what you're doing, but draw your connections with straight lines, not curved.

Comment: @AlanMunn > draw your connections with straight lines. I couldn't find that either in the arrow docs

Comment: Please post compilable code so it's easy for people to reproduce your output. I have no idea what a Mermaid graph is?

Comment: @cfr this is compilable (interpreted) code, [MermaidJS](https://mermaid.js.org/intro/), [Online editor](https://mermaid.live/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Re. compilability: your `forest` code is not compilable as it stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ext.paths.ortho` (part of the [tikz-ext](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-ext/0) library) to draw straight lines between nodes.  Here we use the zigzag path `r-rl` where the `rl` is interpreted to mean first go right, then vertical, then left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        draw,
        align=center
    },
    forked edges,
    [A,name=CEO
        [B
            [C]
            [D,draw,red,name=ME]
        ]
    ]
    \draw (CEO.east) r-rl (ME.east);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 but the doc link doesn't work. (Says it is missing.)

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I've put in a link that works now.

Comment: Looks like a neat bundle. (I skimmed it on CTAN.)